# How to start a system service after mount command

Tags: linux, bash, centos7, systemd

I am working on a lab for my linux class and the teacher is teaching us about Systemd.

**How do I create a service that starts a script when a specific device is mounted using this command:** `mount /dev/xvdc1 /mnt/backup`

What I have tried

1. Using a Timer I checked if `/mnt/backup` was a mount point. (teacher would not accept it. It must be strictly event driven)
2. Creating a .mount unit and making the .service unit require the .mount unit. This approach did not start the script when executing the command: `mount /dev/xvdc1 /mnt/backup`

I think I may be approaching this problem the wrong way. This is the lab problem.

> "Create a unit file that copies all the files from `/mnt/backup`
>   using rsync as soon as `/dev/xvdc1` is mounted."

What I know:

1. The device that will be mounted will always be `/dev/xvdc1`
2. The mount point of the device will always be `/mnt/backup`
3. The Service must be started based on `/dev/xvdc1` being mounted

Here is my .service unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts a backup for /dev/xvdc1 when mounted using the mount command.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/root/backupscript.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: See [**Set systemd service to execute after fstab mount**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246935/set-systemd-service-to-execute-after-fstab-mount) and [**systemd.mount - Freedesktop.org**](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html).  Your question is probably more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/), [**Server Fault**](http://serverfault.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55339527/can-systemd-run-a-script-after-every-mount-regardless-of-the-mount-point

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether this is appropriate in stackoverflow, I don't think [Set systemd service to execute after fstab mount](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246935/set-systemd-service-to-execute-after-fstab-mount) fulfills the Ops requirements - I believe the requirement is that systemd launch a service at the point in time when a mount is performed. Given that, I would have a systemd service unit perform a command `findmnt -pmount -f /mount/point`, and have another systemd unit wait for that.