# Can systemd run a script after every mount, regardless of the mount point?

Tags: systemd

I need to execute a script every time a USB flash drive is inserted.

I can create a systemd service that runs a script after a mount:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script
Requires=run-media-sdb1.mount
After=run-media-sdb1.mount

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bin/my-script

[Install]
WantedBy=run-media-sdb1.mount
```

But this systemd service depends on a special mount point.

How can systemd start a service regardless of the mount point? Irrespective of whether, for example, sda1 or sdc3 is mounted, only one service should be necessary.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Eventually, this link could possibly help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43078579/systemd-execute-script-on-every-mount